# AngularJS Karma Test Spec Promise not resolved and .then() not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, karma-runner, angular-promise

I have a problem with AngularJS Karma Unit Testing a service.

I have a service with a service method like this:

```
service.getIntersectingElements = function (element, elements) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var tolerance = 20;
    var intersectingElements = [];
    $timeout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (element.$$hashKey != elements[i].$$hashKey)
                if (service.checkIntersection(element.Location, elements[i].Location, tolerance))
                    intersectingElements.push(elements[i]);
        }
        if (intersectingElements.length > 0)
            deferred.resolve(intersectingElements);
        else
            deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

It works fine if it is called by the controller. But I want to test that method, which returns a promise resolved later. I want to get the value resolved and compare it in the unit test.

So I wrote the following karma test:

```
it('should get the intersecting elements', function () {
    var element = {Id: 1, Name: 'Water', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}};
    var elements = [{Id: 2, Name: 'Fire', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}}];

    service.getIntersectingElements(element, elements).then(function (result) {
        expect(result).toEqual([{Id: 2, Name: 'Fire', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}}]);
    });
});
```

I call the service method exactly the same as in the controller. But the test ends with a done which is ok. But if I change the line

```
expect(result).toEqual([{Id: 2, Name: 'Fire', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}}]);
```

to

```
expect(result).toEqual("Test");
```

The test is done too and is not failing. But in that case I expect the test to fail.

I already tried injecting the `$rootScope` and calling `$rootScope.$digest();` after the service method call. This should resolve the previous promise, but in fact it did not take any effect, if I place the digest or not...

So my question is, how to test the promise returned by the service method and compare the value resolved and passed to then() of promise in karma unit test.

Edit:
I've tried `$timeout.flush();` and `$rootScope.$digest();` after the service method call.

I injected the services like that if it helps:

```
var service;
var $timeout;
var $rootScope;

beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(module('app.services'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (intersectService, _$timeout_, _$rootScope_) {
    service = intersectService;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does timeout work in angular tests running in karma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484940/how-does-timeout-work-in-angular-tests-running-in-karma)

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue but not using $timeout so I can't flush that.  The promise is from Babel polyfill, the promises are never resolved and I'm not sure how to "flush" them:  https://gist.github.com/Kikketer/1646eccdaff76944b358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it myself...

First... I need to flush the timeout (which I tried earlier) and I need to do a scope apply

```
it('should get the intersecting elements', function () {
    var element = {Id: 1, Name: 'Water', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}, $$hashKey: "1"};
    var elements = [
        {Id: 1, Name: 'Water', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}, $$hashKey: "1"},
        {Id: 2, Name: 'Fire', Location: {x: 200, y: 200}, $$hashKey: "2"}
    ];

    var promise = service.getIntersectingElements(element, elements);

    var result;
    promise.then(function (res) {
        result = res;
    },
    function (error) {
        result = "error";
    });

    $rootScope.$apply();
    $timeout.flush();

    expect(result).toEqual([{Id: 2, Name: 'Fire', Location: {x: 250, y: 200}, $$hashKey: "2"}]);
});
```

The whole thing now looks like that above.

But second... that's not the true mistake. I used The `$$hashKey` property in my service method (see above in question), which is (obviously) not set, because I did not set it in my test data. Normally the `$$hashKey` exists if the variable is on the `$scope`. So I didn't remember to set it.

So the answer to this is to set the `$$hashKey` as seen in the code above.

Answer (score -1):

$$hashKey would not be needed if you use angular.equals because it ignores $* properties (and functions).

`expect(angular.equals(result, [{Id: 2, Name: 'Fire', Location: {x: 250, y: 200}}])).toBe(true);`

I'm adding this as an answer as I do not have enough rep to post a comment.